# json array to php

Tags: php, json

I have array in json, but I want to print it in php.  I get in post this :

```
[{"cartData":{"id":"dragged_567737","left":"255px","top":"71px"}},{"cartData":{"id":"dragged_757836","left":"43px","top":"73px"}}]
```

but when I use print_r($_POST) in my php file, it print me the empty array. 
there is my js code:

```
jQuery('#save_project_data').click( function() {
            var array=[];
            var numItems = $('.icart').length;

            $(".icart").each(function(index) {
                var cart_id = $(this).attr("id");
                var cart_left = $(this).css("left");
                var cart_top = $(this).css("top");

                var cartData = {  
                   "id" : cart_id,                                
                   "left" : cart_left,
                   "top" : cart_top
                };
                queryStr = { "cartData" : cartData };
                array.push(queryStr);
            });

            var postData = JSON.stringify(array);
           $.ajax({
                   url  : "modules/cart_projects/saveData.php",
                   type : "POST",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                   data : postData,//{ 'data': '{"name":"chris"}' }
                   traditional: true,
                   success: function(){
                        alert("OK");
                    } 
               });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass your data as-is? For what reason do you stringify it?

Comment: Which version of php do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has native support for decoding JSON with [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php);

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['myJson']);
print_r($data);
```

The PHP `$_POST` array is interpreted from key value pairs, so you need to change your ajax call like below, because your code is sending the post data with no key.

```
data : { myJson : postData },//{ 'data': '{"name":"chris"}' }
```

If you change the data structure like above, you need to also remove your `application/json; charset=utf-8` content type.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

Comment: @Evaldas Struckus: "it's not work" isn't an issue explanation

Comment: @EvaldasStruckus take out the `application/json; charset=utf-8` content type and set the post key in the javascript (shown in answer).

Comment: NOw in post I got this myJson=%5B%7B%22cartData%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22dragged_790583%22%2C%22left%22%3A%22171px%22%2C%22top%22%3A%22103px%22%7D%7D%5D

Comment: That looks correct. PHP will automatically decode the url encoding, then use json_decode as shown to decode the JSON

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending raw JSON-strings to PHP, $_POST will not be populated (as it needs a standard urlencoded string as submitted by POST requests to decode). You can solve this by either using postData as an object: {'json': json}, so that you get the value in $_POST['json'], or by reading the raw response:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('php://input');
$struct = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use json_decode() function.

Answer (score -1):

According to [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation:

Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. **It's appended to the url for GET-requests.** See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

To be safe, you might be better off using the [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) method.

Finally, I suggest to give the `data` property an `object`. That way you can set an identifier for your post data.

**Javascript**

```javascript
{
    url: 'modules/cart_projects/saveData.php',
    data: {
        mydata: postData
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```php
$_POST['mydata'];
```

If you need to decode the JSON:

```
json_decode($_POST['mydata']);
```

Comment: What would it change? Not an answer.

Comment: "you need" --- actually there is no "need" for that, it's just one of options available.

Comment: "To be safe" --- to be safe from **what**? Stop writing some random phrases ))